# Conditions in yaml pipeline like "eq" and "ne" is not working

Tags: if-statement, build, yaml, azure-pipelines, equals

I have created a pipeline build variable "svctag" and assigned its value to blank (empty string). Now trying to execute below script inside a job in yaml file. Every time it prints "svctag is not blank". Not sure what I am doing wrong.
Please help.

```
- ${{ if eq('$(svctag)', '') }}:
   - script: echo 'svctag is blank'
- ${{ if ne('$(svctag)', '') }}:
   - script: echo 'svctag is not blank'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As I know, this format is only applied in YAML template. Now, the issue is the variable called method you are using is not correct.

You should use the format `variables['svctag']` instead of `$(svctag)` to access the variable which declared previously while you using YAML.

So, you should change your script as

```
  - ${{ if eq(variables['svctag'], '') }}:
    - script: echo it is true 
  - ${{ if ne(variables['svctag'], '') }}:
    - script: echo it is false
```

Here is the output on my side.

[image]

---

Another solution is define `svctag` under `parameters`:

```
parameters:
  svctag: ''
```

Then use parameters with step:

```
  steps:
  - ${{ if eq(parameters.svctag, '') }}:
    - script: echo it is true
  - ${{ if ne(parameters.svctag, '') }}:
    - script: echo it is false
```

Note: Please use `parameters.svctag`.

Comment: really appreciate this thanks! I also figured out that opposite of `in` is `notIn`. When you want to find/exclude a value from list of arguments on the right.

Answer (score 0):

So, you should change your script as

```
  - ${{ if eq(variables['svctag'], '') }}:
    - script: echo it is true 
  - ${{ if ne(variables['svctag'], '') }}:
    - script: echo it is false
```